# How to keep track of your smart contracts without a centralized server?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, dapps

How to keep track of your smart contracts without a centralized server? Let’s say I have a dapp that creates smart contracts. Is there a way I can keep track of all the smart contracts my dapp has made without relying on a centralized database to store their addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a contract which stores the addresses of each of your deployed contracts. Perhaps with `mapping(bytes32 => address) public contract_addresses`;

It could have a function exposed for adding new records to that mapping, which you could make a call to in the constructor of each contract. Just remember to make sure the deploying address is authorized.